# Compiler not working, giving wrong results Dev C++

Tags: c, pointers, dev-c++

I'm facing some error with the compiler or wrong result 'Dev C++' after running following codes. These codes are running perfectly ok in online compilers.
First I ran code below to study about pointers:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    int* pt; int *pt1;
    printf("input"); scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    printf("sum=%d",c=*&a+*&b);
    pt=&c;
    printf("\nPointer result is %d", *pt);
    printf("\nPointed location is %d", pt1);
    printf("\nSize of datatypes (in bytes) of int is %d, char is %d, float is %d", sizeof(int), \
       sizeof(char[100]), sizeof(float));
    printf("\nSize of pointer (in bytes) is %d", sizeof(pt));
}
```

Then the below code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int swap(int*, int*);

int main()
{
    int c,d;
    printf("Input value");
    scanf("%d %d", &c, &d); printf("Entered value c=%d, d=%d", c,d);
    swap(&c,&d);
    printf("\nSwapped c=%d, d=%d", c,d);
}

int swap(int* x, int* y)
{
    int tmp;
    tmp=*x; *x=*y; *y=tmp;
    printf("\nPointed address: %u %u", x,y);
    printf("\nPointed data: %d %d", *x,*y);
    printf("\nSize of pointer= %d bits", 8*sizeof(x));
    return(*x, *y);
}
```

If I run the second code, first is executed, also other codes are giving wrong results. Please help me find a solution.
Result obtained is same for both.

Code 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdxUT.png
Code 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbrto.png

Again I copied the code, pasted and saved it as a new file name 'sample1.cpp'. The code is working. The file names initially used was pointer.cpp for the first and pointer 2.cpp for the second.
Exe file, pointer.exe is declared as a Virus, Trojan:Win32/Sabsik.TE.A!ml by windows defender.

Comment: You are invoking *undefined behavior* by using wrong format specifier and by using value of uninitialized non-static local variable `pt1`, but I see nothing fatally wrong. Please give us some example of input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: @MikeCAT If I execute the second code, I'm getting the output of the first code in the console.

Comment: Then it looks like you are executing the first code. How are you executing them?

Comment: @MikeCAT one after the other. Same result is observed if I close one of them.

Comment: Hi @GaneshMallya, as prompted by MikeCAT,  the way you are invoking/running the executable might be at fault. It will help us identify the source of error if you can provide information as to how you are compiling/running the code (are you using some config script? or direct build etc etc).

Comment: Not directly related, but always check the return value of scanf.

Comment: @lulle In case it read nothing?

Comment: Yes. Return value tells you, how many items of the argument list it successfully filled.  Consider you want to read an int, but user just entered some text. scanf will fail, the only way to know is to check the return value.

Comment: Regarding "If I execute the second code, I'm getting the output of the first code in the console." it sounds like you are using the same name, such as "a.out" for the output of both compilations.

Comment: @vvy I'm not running any config script. I'm getting error in Dev. C++ Compiler. I copied the code into a new .c file with different name, it is working fine.

Comment: @GaneshMallya Could you edit your question and show us a copy of the output you receive?

Comment: @AcidResin done

Comment: Bruh. I meant `Input value 1 3 Entered value c=1, d=3`. Like that

Comment: @AcidResin image changed. Same output is observed for both

Comment: Does the second code accept input? In the screenshot, the program didn't end yet

Comment: @AcidResin Second code is also asking for the same input like the first code.

Comment: Try compiling the program from the command line. `C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe D:\C\pointer.cpp -o pointer.exe` and `C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe "D:\C\Pointer 2.cpp" -o pointer2.exe`. Run the two programs and show us what's the output